# python pass regex to mongo via http

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

i am able to run a simple regex in mongo console :

```
 db.users_exams.count({"id_number": {$regex: /1234/}})
```

Now, my challenge is to pass this regex to mongo after 2 micro services:

```
python micro service -> http request ->  python micro service -> mongo client
```

Tried strings and the `re` library

The point is that python doesn't identify the regex the same as js

```
    a = /1234/
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

I guess my first question is, how to create regex object in python and only then how to pass it in http?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but I guess you need to define an API and use it. E.g. send JSON like {collection: user_exams, action: count, parameters: {"id_number": {$regex: /1234/}}}, or predeine actions in endpoints and do something like POST /api/v1/user_exams/count/regex {id_number: /1234/}

Comment: Hi @AndreyRusanov added my comments in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way :

```
import re 
filter = {'id_number': re.compile("^12348")}
```

or , a little more complex filter

```
import re 
filter = {'id_number': re.compile("^1234[8-9]")}
```